# How to read text from Image in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, image-processing, image-recognition, text-recognition

I have a console application in which I will add image from PC local path, which I want to read the text,hand written values (name and multiple choice values marked as tick) with muliple choice value like as shown in pic.
Which dll or technique could I use to achieve this. I've heard about OCR i also use it but i am unable to achieve my requirements.here is a code of TesseractEngine.

[Output with TesseractEngine lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lqQm.png)

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMP8q.png)

```
var filePath = @"E:\\Test Projects\\ReadDataFromImage\\Untitled.png";
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"E:\Test Projects\ReadDataFromImage\tessdata-main\tessdata-main", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
{
    using (var image = Pix.LoadFromFile(filePath))
    {
        using (var page = engine.Process(image))
        {
            string text = page.GetText();
            Console.WriteLine("Extracted Text:");
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```